# Blocking contextual portlet by default in plone

Tags: portlet, plone

I have a custom portlet manager, and I'd like to blacklist (aka block) context (aka parent) portlets by default. I've found a couple of methods but they either require a specific location (so not sitewide) or will only work if I'm in a different package to where the portlet manager is defined (setuphanders.py is run before portlets.xml is imported and therefore the portlet manager doesn't exist yet), which is not a runner.

What I'd really like to do is use the genericSetup blacklist syntax in portlets.xml with a '*' for the location like this:

```
<blacklist
  manager="custom.portletmanager"
  location="*"
  category="context"
  status="block"
  />
```

But, alas, that doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can override some permission on the portlet (possibly in overrides.zcml), requiring a non-existing permission?

Alternatively, there's a `z3c.unconfigure` package that may be able to unregister the portlet entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never, maybe: using this in your PortletManager's __init _ _ sets the default for inheriting to false, but you can still override it TTW. (This approach does not extend to the other two things, which have a ternary semantic of "block/show/inherit" already, so we can't distinguish a default value from a user-set value and __init _ _ is called every time.)

```
def __init__(self, context, request, view, manager):

    ColumnPortletManagerRenderer.__init__(self, context, request, view, manager)
    assignable = getMultiAdapter((self.context, self.manager,), 
                                 ILocalPortletAssignmentManager)
    if assignable.getBlacklistStatus(CONTEXT_CATEGORY)==None:
        # hack: for CONTEXT, it's a binary flag.
        # Nevertheless, getBlacklistStatus returns ternary True/False/None.
        # None should be the creation default.
        assignable.setBlacklistStatus(CONTEXT_CATEGORY, True)
```